# Cannot deactivate layout constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have designed a part of my user interface in a XIB file using Interface Builder with Autolayout. I created an outlet for one of the layout constraints in the File's Owner class and called it `theHatedConstraint` *(for no particular reason...)*. Now **all I'm trying to do in my code is to switch off that particular constraint** so that the layout machine simply ignores it.

In many other cases I've been able to achieve this behavior by simply setting the constraint's `active` property to `NO`. In this case however, it just doesn't work. Wherever I call

```
self.theHatedConstraint.active = NO;
```

it remains active afterwards as the layout doesn't change in the simulator and the debug view hierarchy (this fancy new 3d debugger thingy in Xcode) still lists the constraint on the respective subview.

I have placed the above code in each of the following methods of my view:

```
-initWithCoder
-awakeFromNib
-updateConstraints
```

all without any effect. If I change the constraint's constant instead of deactivating it, it *does* have the desired effect so I can be sure I have the right constraint and the outlet is set up properly.

The only explanation for this weird behavior is that there must be some kind of mechanism that reactivates `theHatedConstraint` after it's been deactivated. So the next thing I tried was to update the constraint state at a time when I can be sure that all the initialization and loading of the view has finished. I happen to have a collection view as a subview in my custom view so the next thing I did was to call the line of code from above whenever the user taps on any of the collection view cells:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.theHatedConstraint.active = NO;
}
```

and **finally the constraint was removed from the view**.

### So here's the big question:

What happens after `awakeFromNib` and `updateConstraints` have been called in a view, regarding its layout constraints? How can it be that a constraint is still active after I've explicitly set its state to inactive in those methods?

(I'm not touching `theHatedConstraint` anywhere else in my code.)

Comment: Have you ever solved this ? Running through a similar problem here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058648/updating-existing-constraints-does-not-work-wrong-use-of-active-property

Comment: Nope, never solved the problem. Sorry to disappoint you. :(

Comment: Well thank you for answering. This post might give us a clue, in case you face this kind of trouble anytime soon http://useyourloaf.com/blog/animating-autolayout-constraints/